# How do I use the passed value as the default in a dropdown menu?

Tags: php, mysql

--EDITED TO BETTER DESCRIBE THE SCENARIO--

I have a MySQL database containing 2 tables, technicians and work_orders. The technicians table has columns techID, tech_surname, tech_firstname and tech_userlogin. The work_orders table has columnsjobID (PK), wtechID, wtech_surname, wtech_firstname and wtech_userlogin among other things.

I have a page with a repeat region listing submitted work orders, the date of the work order is a link that passes the jobID in a URL to a page containing an update form. The form is populated with data taken from the work_orders table particular the the jobID (customer name, address, equip to repair, problem, etc.). On the form is a dropdown populated from the technicians table. This dropdown lists the tech_userlogin of the technicians. I have included hidden fields to the form page, wtech_userlogin and wtechID. 
When I view the source of the page it shows the values from the work_orders table, but I don't know how to work it into the query to accomplish the desired results.

When the form posts it updates the work_orders table. All of this is working.
What I am hoping to accomplish is to have the wtech_userlogin (from the work_orders table) for the particular work order become the default value of the dropdown menu if a technician has already been selected. If no selection has previously been made from the dropdown menu I would like the default of the dropdown to be "--Select Technician--". I've tried a few things but nothing works so far.

Here is the code for the dropdown:

```
<select name="tech_userlogin" id="tech_userlogin">
              <?php
        $sql="SELECT techID, tech_userlogin FROM technicians";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $techID=$row["techID"];
    $tech_userlogin=$row["tech_userlogin"];
    $options.="<option value=\"$tech_userlogin\">$tech_userlogin</option>";
}

if(empty($tech_userlogin)) {
die ('You must select a Technician');
}

?>
              <option value='<?php echo $options; ?>' selected='selected'>""<?php echo $options; ?>
          </select>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Any assistance will be appreciated. I'm very new at PHP and MySQL. I'm taking a course in web design and we use Dreamweaver. I want to break away from Dreamweaver and learn how to do this without the wizards. I've been able to get my forms to post and all of my insert, update and delete functions work from things I've been able to cobble together from the internet, but this one really has me stumped.

Cheers.

Comment: Why are you capitalizing some elements and attributes and not others? That is really annoying.

Comment: I've taken your suggestion but found your delivery a bit caustic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what you want:

```
<select name="tech_userlogin" id="tech_userlogin">
<?php
    $sql="SELECT techID, tech_userlogin FROM technicians";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $techID = $row['techID'];
        $tech_userlogin=$row['tech_userlogin'];

        // Here - check if the tech id in the query matches the logged in tech's id
        $selected = ($techID == $_SESSION['techID']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

        echo '<option value="' . $tech_userlogin . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $tech_userlogin . '</option>' . "\n";
    }

?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I want to do is pass the value of a previously selected tech_userlogin. For instance, a tech has been assigned to the job, but the details of the job need to be changed. So when the update page populates it populates the dropdown with that previously selected value (the tech_userlogin already selected). If no technician has been assigned then I want the default on the dropdown to be blank or ---Select Tech--- or some such thing.

Comment: You could change `$techID == $_SESSION['techID']` to `$tech_userlogin == $_GET['tech_userlogin']`

Comment: Hi. It's still not working. When the update form posts it updates the work_orders table. The value from the dropdown menu is stored as wtech_userlogin in work_orders. The techID is a hidden field on the form and updates the work_orders table as wtechID. The value I'm trying to get to show in the dropdown field is wtech_userlogin from the work_orders table. Do I need to include the work_orders table in the query? If so, how would I do that. Thank you for your help. Cheers.

Comment: are you using `method="post"` on your form? If so, use `$_POST['tech_userlogin']` instead of `$_GET['tech_userlogin']`. You left out a lot of data :)

Comment: I'm very new at this. The situation is this. I have a repeat region listing all the work orders. When I click on a work order I am directed to the update page with the form. The jobID (PK of work_orders table) passes as URL. The update form is populated with the data that corresponds with that particular jobID. On the update page is a dropdown menu that is populated from a different table in the database, technicians. The form posts and the results are stored in the work_orders table. I want the dropdown default value to be populated with the value from the work_orders table, wtech_userlogin.

Comment: is it passed in the url as `..?wtech_userlogin=foobar` ? If so, you just need to reference that variable. Variables passed in the URL get added to the superglobal `$_GET` array, so you can always find it in `$_GET['wtech_userlogin']` which would have the value `foobar`. In your loop, you just need to check if the *current* iteration value matches the value passed in the URL ($_GET). If it does, you add the `selected="selected"` to that one option.

Comment: Good on ya mate!! That's exactly what I needed. My inexperience and lack of knowledge has been the thing that hampered me most. Your suggestions worked wonderfully. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code have many problems. Let's start with the fact that I do not see where you specify the selection. You should send it to the script via a post. Then, you concatenate option tags in a string, and then add that string as a value to another option. And finally, your variable $tech_userlogin is the value of the column tech_userlogin of the last row in the database table technicians.

EDIT 1: See comment please.

Let's try to fix it:

```
<?php
    // first thing: check if a post was sent
    if($_POST)
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['technician']))
        {
            @session_start();
            $_SESSION['tech'] = $tech;
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_SESSION['tech']))
    {
        $tech = $_SESSION['tech'];
    }
    echo '<form action="" method="post">


    $sql = "SELECT `techID`,`tech_userlogin` FROM `technicians`";
    $sql = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!mysql_num_rows($sql))
    {
        echo 'There is no technician in the database'; // or use die for radical thinking
    }

    $options = '';
    $technicians = array();
    echo '<select name="tech_userlogin" id="tech_userlogin">';
            if(empty($tech))
            {
                echo '<option value="">-- Select technician --</option>';
            }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
         $technicians[] = $row;
         $options .= '<OPTION VALUE="'.$tech_userlogin.'" '.((!empty($tech) && $tech == $tech_userlogin)) ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$tech_userlogin.'</option>';
    }

    echo $options;
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Please submit you selection" />';
    echo '</form>';

?>
```

I hope it helps :).

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I think perhaps I've not been clear on what I would like to do. The tech_userlogin comes from the technicians table. When a tech_userlogin is selected from the dropdown that value then posts to the work_orders table where it is stored as wtech_userlogin along with the other details of a particular job. So if the work order is edited after a tech has been assigned I want the default value of the dropdown to be populated with the tech_userlogin that matches wtech_userlogin from the work_orders table for that particular job. Let me know if that is clear. Cheers

Comment: Well, now I got it... it will require a bit more code. And another select, or a join in the sql statement. Can you please explain a bit further how does the work_orders table looks like, I mean, you could do something like this: $query = 'SELECT * FROM `works_order` where `wtech_userlogin` = "'.$tech_userlogin.'"';  BUT, you see there may be more than one technician in that table. Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, the work_orders table has a field wtech_login its value comes from the technicians table field tech_userlogin. So, when a tech_userlogin is selected from the dropdown that value is posted and stored in the work_orders table. I agree about the query, but don't know how to join the tables. techID is stored in work_orders (for a particular job) as wtechID and tech_userlogin as wtech_userlogin. Is this what you mean?